# Looking for specific video processing example

Tags: reference-request, video

I while back, I was just looking around in the example/demonstrations section of Mathematica, and I came across a couple of very good examples of Video processing in Mathematics. I vaguely remember that I was based on some kind of analysis of Disney video [mean color for animated film...]. However, I am not able to find it any more. Not to say it has disappeared, but my memories for this is so faint, that I may not be looking at the right place. When I search for "video processing" I get Mathematica training videos.

Maybe someone on this list remembers the example and can point me to the relevant section?

Further, I am looking for this example, becaise currently I have a need to prototype some video processing example, and I plan to use Mathematica. It would be nice to hear of experiences of the prople in this group on how they have used Mathematica for video processing.

Thanks,
   Sid.

Answer (score 5):

- The last example in this talk is processing of a video with irregularly timed frames in order to measure the period of the filmed pendulum. Notebook with code is also available for download.

  [Image Processing: Real-World Applications](https://www.wolfram.com/training/videos/IMG003/)
- See my answer to [Tracking a point in a video](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/130861)
- [How to make 360 degree videos](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/782460)
- For correlated frames processing [see example in docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageFeatureTrack.html) in the application section:

  [image]

Answer (score 1):

Found it!!
http://blog.wolfram.com/2013/08/13/a-visit-to-disneys-magic-kingdom/

Thanks for the other answers as well!.

Sid.