# Code behind these Video Playback demos?

Tags: graphics, dynamic, packages, video

There are only two known examples of video playback (from a file) within a (non-cloud) notebook:

1. [Visualizations in Graph Theory with the Wolfram Language](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pQfffi6XLjU&list=PLxn-kpJHbPx0xBVkORRdoQbahhhE8Sn04&index=16) (at time 3:32)
2. [Mathematica and CUDA, SIGGRAPH 2010](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jXvM1ZRu8E4) (at time 4:19)

Does anyone have access to these packages, or know how this wizardry was achieved?

**Related:**

- Related to this question, but mine is much more specific: [Video processing in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/106256/video-processing-in-mathematica)
- [Video encodings in Ubuntu](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77682/video-encodings-in-ubuntu)
- About encodings: [Import[] bug (video)?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10635/import-bug-video)

Comment: [Sollami's Presentation Notebook](http://wac.36f4.edgecastcdn.net/0036F4/pub/www.wolfram.com/technology-conference/2016/SollamiWTC2016VisualizationsAndGraphTheory.nb)

Comment: @kglr Nice find, but that notebook has some dependencies - it imports some other package called mma_video.wl

Comment: @user5601 if you want Michael's package you can find him on GitHub: https://github.com/msollami and he'll likely be willing to share