# How to play local MP4 video?

Tags: video

In Python Notebook I can insert a local MP4 video by doing this:

[image]

Is there a way to implement similar functionality in Mathematica?

Comment: MP4 is not listed in the [supported multimedia formats](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/MultimediaFormats.html); you may have to convert your video to \*.avi or QuickTime format first with an external program before you can import it to *Mathematica*.

Comment: Very closely related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/163008/38205

Comment: Out-of-core [`Video`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Video.html) is now supported in 12.1 including MPEG and H264/H265 in an MP4 container. See also `VideoExtractFrames`